# How to create indicator columns in a pandas dataframe based on groups in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe **df** of the form:

```
    Object   Class1    Class2    Class3    Class4    Class5     .... Other random columns
    Apple       1        0          1         1         1
    Orange      0        1          0         0         0
    Grape       0        0          0         0         0
    Banana      1        1          0         0         0
    Guava       1        0          0         0         0
```

I have another dataframe **df2** that provides groupings for the class columns above

```
   Class    Group
   Class1   Group1
   Class2   Group2
   Class3   Group2
   Class4   Group1
   Class5   Group3
```

What I want to do is take the groupings from df2 and create indicator columns back in df. More clearly, I want:

```
    Object   Class1    Class2    Class3    Class4    Class5    Group1    Group2    Group3     .... Other random columns
    Apple       1        0          1         1         1        1         1         1 
    Orange      0        1          0         0         0        0         1         1
    Grape       0        0          0         0         0        0         0         0
    Banana      1        1          0         0         0        1         1         0
    Guava       1        0          0         0         0        1         0         0
```

What is a good way to create this? I would be grateful if I can get a solution that's easy to understand and not necessarily too pythonic as I'm trying to learn more about how pandas works.

Comment: what is the logic of the values 1 and 0 ?

Comment: 1 indicates the value is present. For example, Apple falls under class 1, 2 and 3. In turn class 1 belongs to group 1. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In panda we can pass `mapping` when we do `groupby` , here `df2` is your `mapping`

```
df=df.join(df.reindex(df2.Class,axis=1).\
        groupby(df2.set_index('Class').Group.to_dict(), axis=1).max())
df
Out[204]: 
   Object  Class1  Class2  Class3  Class4  Class5  Group1  Group2  Group3
0   Apple       1       0       1       1       1       1       1       1
1  Orange       0       1       0       0       0       0       1       0
2   Grape       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
3  Banana       1       1       0       0       0       1       1       0
4   Guava       1       0       0       0       0       1       0       0
```

Comment: How are we picking the relevant columns here from df? Df can have other columns that are not represented in df2.

Comment: Thanks YOBEN_S, this works! I was wondering if this  can work with one small change? Basically, the values in Class1, Class2 etc in df can be non-integers (like 0.4, 0.3...etc) If they are non-zero, I would like the Group1, Group2 Group3 values to still be 1s. Is that possible?

Comment: @Melsauce df=df.join(df.reindex(df2.Class,axis=1).\
        groupby(df2.set_index('Class').Group.to_dict(), axis=1).max().ne(0).astype(int))